# Number of functioning CPUs

Tags: multithreading, ubuntu, cpu-usage

My operating system shows I'm having 32 cores in my CPU however, any program I run written by me or downloaded shows only 20. Any clarification please?

I have attached screenshots for more illustration. Thanks!
[image: OS_screenshot] [image]

Comment: That's why I said even codes I download have the same behavior. The behavior is general.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and SuperUser cover more general questions that include hardware.

Answer (score 0):

try use some miner like xmr-stak and check if they can detect all the cores